# How can we do counts of items in a data frame and asign results to a new column in the dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have street addresses that look like this.

```
250 EAST HOUSTON STREET
211 EAST 3RD STREET
182 EAST 2ND STREET
511 EAST 11TH STREET
324 EAST 4TH STREET
324 EAST 4TH STREET
324 EAST 4TH STREET
324 EAST 4TH STREET
324 EAST 4TH STREET
324 EAST 4TH STREET
324 EAST 4TH STREET
324 EAST 4TH STREET
754 EAST 6TH STREET
```

How can I get counts, in the same data frame, like this?

```
250 EAST HOUSTON STREET 3
211 EAST 3RD STREET     1
182 EAST 2ND STREET     1
511 EAST 11TH STREET    1
324 EAST 4TH STREET     8
324 EAST 4TH STREET     8
324 EAST 4TH STREET     8
324 EAST 4TH STREET     8
324 EAST 4TH STREET     8
324 EAST 4TH STREET     8
324 EAST 4TH STREET     8
324 EAST 4TH STREET     8
754 EAST 6TH STREET     1
```

The name of the field that I want to count is 'Street'.  I found some code that counts dupes, but it does a group by and takes everything into a new data frame.  I want to assign counts to a new column in the same data frame.  Thanks!

Comment: What's the code you found? It should be fairly straightforward to redirect the output from a new df to a column in the existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` + `transform`. Transform allows you to call the series to a new column. If you do not use transform, then you have a consolidated series that is a mismatch for the dataframe and your column will instead be filled with `NaN` values:

```
import pandas as pd
# df = pd.read_clipboard('\s\s+', header=None).rename({0: 'Street'}, axis=1) # how I read in your data from your StackOverflow question
df['Count'] = df.groupby('Street')['Street'].transform('count')
df
Out[1]: 
                     Street  Count
0   250 EAST HOUSTON STREET  1
1       211 EAST 3RD STREET  1
2       182 EAST 2ND STREET  1
3      511 EAST 11TH STREET  1
4       324 EAST 4TH STREET  8
5       324 EAST 4TH STREET  8
6       324 EAST 4TH STREET  8
7       324 EAST 4TH STREET  8
8       324 EAST 4TH STREET  8
9       324 EAST 4TH STREET  8
10      324 EAST 4TH STREET  8
11      324 EAST 4TH STREET  8
12      754 EAST 6TH STREET  1
```

Comment: Thanks Davide, but when I run that, I get: KeyError: 0

Comment: @Ash `df['Count'] = df.groupby('Street')['Street'].transform('count')` I have also updated my answer to name the column '`Street'` instead of `0`

Answer (score 0):

I'm really new to trying to help people on this platform so feel free to tell me I'm not looking in the right places for the info, but are you using Pandas or another library?
If you're using Pandas I think there's a method called valuecount (maybe value_count) that could be useful. Sorry I can't be more helpful but I'm learning the ropes here.

Comment: that is a good idea, but per my answer, just like a groupby, that would consolidate the values. The OP wants to have these values repeated in a column.

Comment: The reason why this doesn't work is because you cannot call a consolidated array or series with less rows than the rows of the dataframe. It has to be the same number of rows. Transform keeps the same number of rows.

Comment: I wanted to keep the same number of rows that the original data frame had. I can make an argument for group by and sum, or keep the data frame the unchanged and append a new field with counts of items. I completely understand the former option, but in this case, I wanted the latter option, which is totally different. Thanks David!